# Schengen visa itinerary changes

Tags: schengen, itineraries

If there’s a change in itinerary after the issue of Schengen visa, do we need to update to the embassy?
If yes, how?
Is there any chances of rejection?

Comment: It could depend on factors such as how material the change is, to get an answer you need to provide more information. There are several [related questions here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/schengen-overview-community-wiki-to-avoid-duplicates) where you might find an answer.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/188249/schengen-visa-traveling-long-after-initial-itinerary

Comment: Much more information is needed here. You might review [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/188249/schengen-visa-traveling-long-after-initial-itinerary/188251?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#188251) and [this other one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181747/adding-more-countries-after-schengen-visa-is-issued) to help you understand the concept of "main destination" which could apply here. Too, you can search using the "Search on Travel" box at the top of the page, for "Schengen visa itinerary change." There are lots of questions about this issue.